# how to mock a void method in powermock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, powermock

How to mock a void  method which is non-static, non-finalThe signature of method is as below. I'm using Powermockito.

```
public class Name{

public void methodName{
...
...
}
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Name.class})
public class TestClass{
@Test
public void testMethodName(){
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Name.class, methodName);
//some  when calls after this and assert later on
}
```

I want to DO Nothing when methodName is called. the above code is not working. it says methodName cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to mock a non-static method you need to specify the mock object:

```
public class Name{
    public void methodName{
        ...
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Name.class})
public class TestClass{
    @Test
    public void testMethodName(){

        Name myName = PowerMockito.mock(Name.class);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(myName).methodName();

        //some  when calls after this and assert later on
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use PowerMock.createmock() for Mocking your Class Where method is There.
For e.g you have ClassA and methodA which is a Void Method.
Then You can Mock it in a below way:

```
A a = PowerMock.CreateMock(A.class);
a.methodA();
PowerMock.replay(a);
```

Note : in above case method a is void That's the reason EasyMock.expect is not return;

Answer (score -1):

I'm not at an IDE at the moment, but I think you can do this:

```
final Name name = mock(Name.class);
doNothing().when(name).methodName();
```

Comment: i tried it but of no use. its actually calling the original methodName() method for some reason instead of mocking the call.

Comment: What do you mean by 'no use', did you get an error, or did you observe some unexpected behaviour?

Comment: sorry.it didnt work as expected.it was calling the original method instead of mocking the call and not doing anything. which was was i was expecting